# jMeter Server Mode - Windows can not find "rmiregistry"

Tags: jmeter

When I try to execute jMeter in server mode, I get this exception:

> `"Windows can not find 'rmiregistry'"`

. I don't know how to solve this, I googled about it, but I didn't find anything related to my problem.

Comment: Do you have more log information about the error?

Comment: @Superfilin, I dont. Whe I run jmeter-server.bat I get a messagebox with this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have the rmiregistry in your path.  Make sure the java\bin directory is in your path.

Once that's done, to check it's working:

```
Start -> Run -> cmd -> start rmiregistry
```

If that doesn't work, check your path again.

You may need to start the registry yourself, before running the jmeter-server.bat.  Additionally, edit the batch file to make sure it's running with the correct server settings.

Comment: It worked for me. You need to check environment variable (Path variable in windows) is set. For me which is: D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin

Answer (score 3):

Dylan's answer is the most likely, but just to add clarification, your path is stored as an environment variable in Windows. From the command line, you can run:

```
echo %PATH%
```

To see the value of the variable. You should see a semi-colon delimited output of various directory paths.

To append to the variable (if java\bin isn't in there) use the following:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;[full path to java\bin]
```

To check that the RMI registry has started correctly, you can check that it is listening on its standard port (1099 unless you've specified otherwise) with a tool such as TCP View.